# Google Oauth 2.0 app doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to integrate with Google Oauth 2.0 and have got as far as getting the authorization token. When trying to fetch for the access and refresh tokens I keep getting an error about my app not complying with validation rules. My app is still in testing mode, and I have valid redirect urls configured. Any one know what I might have misconfigured?

{
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure. You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules."
}

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: a) What redirect URIs are you using?
If you're using a possibly insecure URL, see the redirect URI and JS origin validation rules: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#uri-validation

b) How are you signing the user in? If you're using embedded webviews, Google OAuth is not allowed to be used in embedded webviews.

Comment: a) Because this is a test, I've been using the google playground as my redirect url (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground). I've also added this redirect uri as one in my app. I've also tried redirecting to our main apps home page, which is also https:// which didn't work.

Comment: b) I'm signing in using the below url. Was able to go through the consent screen just fine and got the authorization token.
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=<my_client_id>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fadmin.directory.user.readonly+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.events.readonly+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&access_type=offline

Comment: how to solve this i am currently  on localhost and on http://